# Range must be bounded by constant expressions - Verilog

Tags: verilog

How can I write in Verilog the following lines of code :

```
SF_D <= RAW1_i[(127 - (8*bytes_cnt)) : (124 - (8*bytes_cnt))];
SF_D <= RAW1_i[((8*bytes_cnt)-1) : ((8*bytes_cnt)-4)];
```

It gives me an error saying `Range must be bounded by constant expressions.`
`bytes_cnt` is changing value, is a counter, so I guess this is the problem. With constant value it works, with dynamic it doesn't. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use part-select (`-:` and `+:`). A description and examples can be found in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 11.5.1 *Vector bit-select and part-select addressing*. First IEEE appearance is IEEE 1364-2001 (Verilog) § 4.2.1 *Vector bit-select and part-select addressing*.

Example:

```
SF_D <= RAW1_i[ 124 - (8*bytes_cnt) +: 4];
SF_D <= RAW1_i[ (8*bytes_cnt)-1 -: 4];
```

Also discussed on stack overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067571
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778418

Comment: Thank you. It works ! I have one more question, how can I write the following line such that it can be synthesizable in Xilinx ISE 14.7 `SF_D <=  RAW[ 252 - (8*bytes_cnt) +: 4] ; ` It gives the following error: `Index 510 is not in range of signal <RAW>.`. `bytes_cnt` is a 6 bit counter, with maximum value 32 . `RAW` is a 256 bit wire